# Will saving a model create an id on server and sync back to client?

Tags: backbone.js

When saving model to the server, will the model on the client's side be updated with the id of the model stored in the database? For example

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend();
var me = new Person();
me.save();
```

After the previous operation, what will be the value of `me.get('id')`? Does it depend on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When saving model to the server, will the model on the client's side be updated with the id of the model stored in the database?

Yes, if the server response for the save request contains an `id` attribute corresponding to the id in database.
In case if the name of the property containing database id in server response is not exactly `id` (for example mogodb based server usually responds with `_id`), you can use the [`idAttribute`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute) option to specify the property name which will contain the database `id` in server response.

If your server response doesn't contain an `id` attribute, or if the database id in server response is having a different property name than `id` but you didn't set [`idAttribute`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute) in model, then No.

> After the previous operation, what will be the value of `me.get('id')`? Does it depend on the server?

totally depends on the server response and your modal configuration (`idAttribute`)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following:

http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-51

Backbone **Models** are the basic data object in the framework – frequently representing a row in a table in a database on your server. A discrete chunk of data and a bunch of useful, related methods for performing computations and transformations on that data.

Create a new model with the specified attributes. A client id (`cid`) is automatically generated and assigned for you.

```
var Model = Backbone.Model = function(attributes, options) {
    var attrs = attributes || {};
    options || (options = {});
    this.cid = _.uniqueId(this.cidPrefix);
    this.attributes = {};
    if (options.collection) this.collection = options.collection;
    if (options.parse) attrs = this.parse(attrs, options) || {};
    var defaults = _.result(this, 'defaults');
    attrs = _.defaults(_.extend({}, defaults, attrs), defaults);
    this.set(attrs, options);
    this.changed = {};
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

The server takes care of giving you IDs. You don't always push to the server or you haven't gotten a response yet. What to do?

This is why Backbone models have another id: the "`client id`". This id (`Model.cid`) is guaranteed to be unique whether the `Model.id` is unique or not and is set in the constructor. If you need to work with model IDs on the client, you can always use `Model.cid` instead of `Model.id` to be safe.